# pandas dataframeの列名に〇〇を含む要素を抽出しさらに値にフィルターをかける方法

Tags: python, pandas

下記のdataframeに対して
「labelが1かつ列名にP1を含む列の値が1以上かつ列名にP3を含む列の値が1以上の要素を抽出」
という処理を加えたいです。

Pythonコードの例をご教示頂けますでしょうか。

dataframe
[image: Input data]
↓
↓
Output data
(labelが0のもの以外にも、列名にP1とP3を含む列の値が全て0のものも抽出していない)
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

「列名に**P1**を含む列」は `df.columns.str.contains('P1')` なので、「列名に**P1**を含む列の値が（１つでも）1以上の行」 は `(df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('P1')] >= 1).any(axis=1)` となります。

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html

ということで、「**label**が1かつ列名に**P1**を含む列の値が（１つでも）1以上かつ列名に**P3**を含む列の値が（１つでも）1以上の要素を抽出」は

```
df[(df.loc[:,'label'] == 1) & (df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('P1')] >= 1).any(axis=1) & (df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('P3')] >= 1).any(axis=1)]
```

のようにかけます。

ただ今回の場合は「列名に**P1**を含む列」というより、「列名が**P1**から始まる列」として、`df.columns.str.startswith('P1')` を使うほうが適当なきがします。

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html

```
df[(df.loc[:,'label'] == 1) & (df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith('P1')] >= 1).any(axis=1) & (df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith('P3')] >= 1).any(axis=1)]
```

さらには、カラム名の並びが既知であるならば、単純にSliceでもよいのではないでしょうか

```
df[(df.loc[:,'label'] == 1) & (df.loc[:,'P1S1':'P1S3'] >= 1).any(axis=1) & (df.loc[:,'P3S1':'P3S3'] >= 1).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: 質問にて「P1を含む列の値が1以上」とありますが、「列名にP1を含む列の値が（１つでも）1以上の行」なのか「列名にP1を含む列の値が（全て）1以上の行」では全く違う結果となりますので、質問をする際はこのあたりを明確にしてください。　（今回は出力値から前者であると推定して回答しております）

Comment: 誠にありがとうございます。また質問の精緻さについても承知いたしました。回答結果は推定して頂いた通りの内容で合っております。誠にありがとうございます。